# Unable to use chromedriver in Selenium after providing path of chrome driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

import option is not displaying

[image]

I have provided the chromedriver path but I am unable import
"import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;" this command. Please provide a solution

Comment: Did you google for a solution at all? There are a million guides on the web on how to install Chrome and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just set the path of `ChromeDriver` & start using it. The `Chromedriver` is an executable file used by Selenium's `WebDriver` to control chrome. So first you need to configure your project for Selenium.

[Configure Eclipse with Selenium WebDriver](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/) is the best resource to setup Selenium on Eclipse.

Once your are done with the configuration, to correctly use `ChromeDriver`, use the statement:

`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome driver like this by providing your Chrome driver path:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add selenium jars before you try to execute any selenium script.  It seems you only added java jars.

Comment: It's better you updated your question, instead of write this as an answer.